# Java float to double - upper and lower bounds?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision, ieee-754

As most here will know, double -> float incurs a loss in precision. This means, multiple double values may be mapped to the same float value.
But how do I go the other way? Given a normal (I'm not caring about the extreme cases) float, how do I find the upper and lower value of double precision that are still mapped to the same float?

Or, to speak in code:

```
function boolean testInterval(float lowF, float highF, double queryD) {
    float queryF = (float) queryD;
    return (lowF <= queryF) && (queryF <= highF);
}
```

and

```
function boolean testInterval(float lowF, float highF, double queryD) {
    double lowD = (double) lowF;
    double highD = (double) highF;
    return (lowD <= queryD) && (queryD <= highD);
}
```

do not always give the same result. I'm looking for two functions float-> double to make the second function return the same result at the first.

This could work, but it looks like a hack and not the proper solution to me.

```
function boolean testIntervalHack(float lowF, float highF, double queryD) {
    double lowD = (double) lowF - Float.MIN_VALUE;
    double highD = (double) highF + Float.MIN_VALUE;
    return (lowD <= queryD) && (queryD <= highD);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `testIntervalHack` doesn't work, the range of `double` values mapping to the same `float` varies. For example, with `x = 2^24-1`, every `double` between `x-0.5` and `x+0.5` will be mapped to the same value (the `float` value of `x`), but `x +/- Float.MIN_VALUE == x`.

I'm not aware of any convenient API methods, so the best I can offer is

1. convert to `double`
2. convert the `double` to the bit representation via `doubleTo(Raw)LongBits`
3. add or subtract one of 2<sup>28</sup> or 2<sup>28</sup>-1, depending on whether you want the upper or lower bound and the 2<sup>29</sup>-bit is 0 or 1 (because of round-to-even)
4. convert that long to double via `longBitsToDouble`

Well, that's for finite values in `float` range. For `NaN`s, you can stop after step 1., for infinities, it's a bit more delicate, since `double` values larger than or equal to 2<sup>128</sup>-2<sup>103</sup> are converted to `(float)Infinity`, which is quite a bit away from the bit representation of `(double)Infinity`.

Comment: Thanks. Infinites and NaN are outside of my scope. I feared that I need to work with the bit representation already. :-(

Comment: So I seem to have it working for NaN, Infinity, +-0 and normal values. I didn't pay attention to the 2^29 bit yet. Can you elaborate on that? And I'm still having trouble with subnormal values.